# Nestjs: req.user is undefined in middleware and Guard, but available in interceptor

Tags: jwt, nestjs, passport.js

Yo!
Here is the AuthGuard:

```
export class AccessTokenStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, AccessJwtStrategyAlias) {
    constructor() {
        super({
            jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
            ignoreExpiration: false,
            secretOrKey: process.env.ACCESS_JWT_SECRET_KEY
        })
    }

    async validate(payload: any) {
        return { ...payload };
    }
}
```

Here @AuthGuard is merged with another decorator:

```
export function AccessJwtAuthGuard() {   
   return applyDecorators(
    UseGuards(AuthGuard(AccessJwtStrategyAlias)),
    ApiBearerAuth('access-token')   ); }
```

And here we apply it to the controller:

```
@Controller('user')
@AccessJwtAuthGuard()
export class UserController {}
```

I've created a logger middleware and applied it to the app globally in AppModule:

```
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer
      .apply(LoggerMiddleware)
      .forRoutes('*')
  }
}
```

The question:
req.user in undefined in middleware. Same stuff with a custom Guard. Only if I use an interceptor I finally see req.user.

Is there a way I can access req.user in my middleware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`req.user` gets populated by the return of the `validate` in the `PassportStrategy`, which is called by the `AuthGuard('strategy')`. Because Nest has a [specific execution order](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/request-lifecycle#summary) the middleware will **never** populate `req.user` unless you set the value yourself. It *will* be populated in guards that run *after* `AuthGuard()`, but not ones that run before it